# Unable to load dse package in R

Tags: r, package

I am using R 2.11.1 on Windows Vista. When I try to load the package `dse`, the following error shows up:

```
Loading required package: dse
Error : object 'Tobs' not found whilst loading namespace 'dse'
Error: package 'dse' could not be loaded
```

Is this a known problem, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps you should install the latest version of R first and try again? I have just successfully installed and loaded the package from R 2.13.0 on Win7.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick Sabbe said, using the latest versions often works wonders.

Just for the record, the problem was probably trying to use a new version of `dse` with an old version of `tframe`. When I load `dse` I get

```
> library(dse)
Loading required package: tframe
Loading required package: setRNG
```

The [news for `dse`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dse/NEWS) says

```
Changes in dse version 2011.3-1

   o    Changed periods() and tfperiods() to Tobs() to be consistent with
    changes in tframe.
```

The [news for `tframe`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tframe/NEWS) says

```
Changes in tframe version 2011.3-1

   o    Changed periods() and tfperiods() (distinction no longer needed) 
    to Tobs() to avoid conflicts with other packages.
```